# How can I beautify asset URLs in Yii?

Tags: php, url, yii

Yii has a notion of *assets* -- resources such as images, stylesheets and javascript that belong to a module. To avoid naming conflicts among modules, Yii publishes a module's assets, on demand, to a uniquely-named subfolder of the web app's assets folder.

For example, the project that is auto-generated by yiic serves HTML pages that link to jquery as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/myproject/assets/b420fe6b/jquery.js"></script>
```

How can I change "b420fe6b" into something more readable (while still getting the benefits of assets and modules)? I would like what people see in "view source" to be clean and readable, not just the source code on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/

Yii docs explain these Asset urls to be "*a unique name created by Yii in a way that won't conflict with any other module that publishes assets*"

Looks like this is a feature that may not be able to be beautified due to its functional nature as serving as a unique identifier...

**Update:**
However, if you are able to locate all places where your asset urls are referenced in your yii code (including finally the folder name itself) you might be able to change them to something easier on the eyes. (*Don't recommend it though as you never know what you might brake! -- and on the 1 in 10,000,000,000 chance that the next asset-url that yii creates is identical to the beautified one lol*)

Comment: Is there any way to tell the asset manager to use a readable ID picked by me that I know is unique within my project? (Or to use the module name as a default ID, unless the rare situation of two identically-named modules arises?)

Comment: Looking at the CAssetManager docs it does not look like the class provides any methods / properties that allow you to set the asset-url...You might just have to do it manually (Rename it yourself after creation, and then find all references and rename them...) Might work but it would be a hack.

Comment: I suspected it might not be possible. Thanks for confirming it. I will wait for a while and then accept your answer (unless someone comes up with an amazing technique that you and I both overlooked).

Comment: No problem. That'd be cool if someone did have a non-hack solution to this -- I'd be interested to see how it would be done.